# Probably a newbie question about Python. Running into an error for automated downloads from Braintree

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, braintree

Using Python script to automatically download Braintree Transactions. Keep running into this error. This is probably a very basic question. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried downloading module from Github. Did not work.

```
import braintree
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(
  braintree.Configuration(
    braintree.Environment.Production
merchant_id`
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7543c1a1e631> in <module>()
----> 1 import braintree
  2 from datetime import datetime
  3 from datetime import timedelta
  4 import csv
  5 from collections import OrderedDict

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'braintree'
```

Comment: How did you try to download it?

Comment: Importing it into the Lib folder. I did get it to work, but now have a new problem with line 43 of the code (csvwriter module).

Comment: File "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Braintree Test.py", line 43, in <module>
    csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Code in question:
     csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(resultFile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))